# How to get cats to stop eating sound proofing material

Tags: cats, training

I have sound proofing/deadening material up on my walls to help acoustics, but our cats like to eat it some times, and I can't imagine that's good for them.

Is there something we could make/get to spray on the foam that would deter the cats from eating it? They do this when no one is home/sleeping, etc. so we can't be there all the time to physically stop them.

Obviously taking the foam down off the walls is one option, but it would be nice to keep it up *and* stop them from eating it if at all possible.

Comment: are you sure your cats realy is eating it or do they use it as a scratching post.

Comment: Is this throughout your whole house or just one room?

Comment: @trondhansen they're definitely eating it, I've watched them do it before

Comment: @RebeccaRVT I would say about the half of the rooms, I got carried away with how I liked the deadened sound :)

Comment: @BrianLeishman: Not to ignore your reply, but how sure are you that they are **eating** it, and not just chewing on it? Our cats **love** to bite chunks out of cardboard and chew on them, but I noticed that they never swallow any of it. They should stop ruining the foam regardless of their goals, but your approach should be different based on what they're doing with the foam.

Comment: @Flater Ahh I see your point, in that regard, I am not entirely sure whether or not they are really swallowing it or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using a citrus-based "cat repellent" type spray. You can either buy a [ready made one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Bitter-Citrus-Anti-Chew-Repellent-Spray/dp/B00IPBFWW2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1506443050&sr=8-1&keywords=cat+repellent+citrus) or [mix one up at home](http://www.instructables.com/id/Friendly-but-Effective-Cat-Repellent/). Cats hate the scent of citrus so they will generally avoid the area but it's not harmful to them.

You'll want to test any such spray on a discreet area of the foam first obviously to make sure that it doesn't stain the foam as I'm guessing that wouldn't be a good look!

Comment: I did not know this! Yes I will try this tonight when I get home. And luckily the foam is very dark in color, so hopefully that's not an issue :)